# Create a null column with given name, if missing from one dataset

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 5 data sets, each containing some columns. The data sets have common column names, but all columns are not present in all the data sets. So whenever a column name (that appears in at least one of the data set) is not present in some other data set, I want to create a column of all zeros with that column name in that data set. So that all the data sets have same number of columns (and same column names).

Answer (score 1):

Put the dataframes in the list, get the all the `unique` column names present in all the dataframes combined and add columns which are absent in each dataframe with 0.

```
all_names <- unique(unlist(sapply(list_df, names)))
lst1 <- lapply(list_df, function(x) {x[setdiff(all_names, names(x))] <- 0;x})
lst1

#[[1]]
#  a  b c
#1 1  6 0
#2 2  7 0
#3 3  8 0
#4 4  9 0
#5 5 10 0

#[[2]]
#  a  c b
#1 1  6 0
#2 2  7 0
#3 3  8 0
#4 4  9 0
#5 5 10 0

#[[3]]
#  a  c  b
#1 1  6 11
#2 2  7 12
#3 3  8 13
#4 4  9 14
#5 5 10 15
```

If you need separate dataframes you can use `lst1[[1]]`, `lst1[[2]]` individually again.

**data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10)
df2 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, c = 6:10)
df3 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, c = 6:10, b = 11:15)
list_df <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use a `for` loop to do this

```
un1 <- Reduce(union, lapply(lst1, names))
for(i in seq_along(lst1)) lst1[[i]][setdiff(un1, names(lst1[[i]]))] <- 0
```

#### data

```
lst1 <- list(structure(list(a = 1:5, b = 6:10, c = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), 
  row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(a = 1:5, c = 6:10, 
    b = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), 
   row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame"),       
    structure(list(a = 1:5, c = 6:10, b = 11:15), 
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -5L)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use dplyr's `bind_rows`, which automatically fills missing values with NA. If you include `.id = "df_id"` a column will be added connecting each row to the original dataframe:

```r
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(df1, df2, df3, .id = "df_id")

#### OUTPUT ####

  df_id  x  y  z
1     1  1  2 NA
2     2  3 NA  4
3     3 NA  5  6
```

If you want 0s instead of NAs just runt `df[is.na(df)] <- 0`. If you want a more informative `df_id` column you can pass in a named list:

```r
bind_rows(list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3), .id = "df_id")

#### OUTPUT ####

  df_id  x  y  z
1   df1  1  2 NA
2   df2  3 NA  4
3   df3 NA  5  6
```

If you want your dataframes separate then simply split by `df_id`, which generates a list of dataframes:

```r
df <- bind_rows(df1, df2, df3, .id = "df_id")
split(df, df$df_id)

#### OUTPUT ####

$`1`
  df_id x y  z
1     1 1 2 NA

$`2`
  df_id x  y z
2     2 3 NA 4

$`3`
  df_id  x y z
3     3 NA 5 6
```

#### Data:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 2)
df2 <- data.frame(x = 3, z = 4)
df3 <- data.frame(y = 5, z = 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answers, you can use the `bind_rows` function in order to quickly combine all your data frames, which will take care of differences in column names:

```
library(dplyr)

x <- data.frame(
  a = 1:3,
  b = 4:6
)

y <- data.frame(
  a = 4:7
)

z <- data.frame(
  c = 8:10
)

xyz <- bind_rows(x, y, z)

xyz %>% replace(., is.na(.), 0)
```